# .NET MVC: Configuring Unity for (effectively) a per-Request Lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am building an MVC based UI that communicates with a WebAPI 2 REST API. The UI has multiple layers, the bottom being a proxy to the REST API. When a request comes into any MVC Controller we capture some meta-information at the entry point that we want to pass in HTTP headers in our requests to the REST API.

We are using Unity for DI, and registration by convention (and a few items registered explicitly) set up like this:

```
    private static void RegisterByConvention(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var loadedAssemblies = AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(a => a.GetInterfaces()
            .Any(
                i => i.Namespace != null
                     && i.Namespace.StartsWith(ApplicationNamespace))).ToArray();

        container.RegisterTypes(
            loadedAssemblies,
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.PerThread,
            null,
            true);
    }

    private static void RegisterExplicitly(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IWebApiProxy, WebApiProxy>(
            new PerThreadLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(string.Empty, string.Empty, Guid.Empty));
    }
```

Note that I am using *PerThread* lifetime managers in the code above, but I have tried this with virtually all lifetime managers (more on this below). The reason I chose PerThread originally is because, according the [dev guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> For this lifetime manager Unity returns, on a per-thread basis, the
>   same instance of the registered type or object each time you call the
>   Resolve or ResolveAll method or when the dependency mechanism injects
>   instances into other classes. This lifetime manager effectively
>   implements a singleton behavior for objects on a per-thread basis.
>   PerThreadLifetimeManager returns different objects from the container
>   for each thread.

Note that all of our MVC controllers inherit from a base controller that has this method:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // gather meta data... 
        this._container.RegisterInstance(
            new WebApiProxy(metaData1, metaData2, metaData3));
    }
```

The idea here is that for *each call* coming into an MVC Controller we will register a new instance of the WebApiProxy that will be used further down the call chain constructed with the appropriate meta data. The goal here is to abstract away handling this meta data so devs don't have to pass it down the stack absolutely everywhere we need to make a call to the WebApiProxy.

However... There are issues. I've found that, with multiple calls with varying metadata passed into the overridden "OnActionExecuting" function, sometimes the call will use an instantiation of the WebApiProxy with *old metadata*.

I have a feeling the issue is with my configuration and (hopefully) not a greater issue with using the DI container for this purpose. Anyone who can guide me on how to guarantee to always have the same data that was used in the overridden "OnActionExecuting" function be available in the WebApiProxy instantiation within the same call chain would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT:***
One thing to note, I'm using async and await from the entrypoint to the WebApiProxy, but I don't *think* that should have any affect on the behavior here.

***EDIT 2:***
Well, I gave up on this technique for now and am using the HttpContext to store and reference the metadata I need down the stack. I'll come back to a figuring out a way to implement this with the DI container later.